# LVM volumes on an external SSD in 19.10

Tags: ssd, external-hdd, lvm

I have a USB3 SSD which is an LVM VG and PV with two LVs on it.  When I first insert the device, everything works fine; the volumes show up as `/dev/dm-X` and links are created in `/dev/mapper/<volume_name>`.  If I then remove the device and re-insert it, it doesn't work.  The mapper devices are not removed when the disk is removed and even if I remove them manually, they are not recreated when the disk is reinserted.

Is this a know defect?  Can I configure around this?  Is there a way to recover this without rebooting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have a fix for this, but some notes:

Pulling the plug on an LVM2 volume is not a good idea.  Clean up properly if you can.  To take such a disk offline:

```
$ vgchange -a n <vg-name>
$ udisksctl lock -b /dev/sd<X>
```

If you get in a mess with a disk that's been pulled, then you need to clean each logical volume up separately with:

```
$ dmsetup remove <lv-name>
```

After doing this, re-inserting the disk will do the right thing and map all the volumes correctly.

Comment: I suspect that if my udev-fu was up to it, I could use this to write a rule that correctly removes all the mapper volumes when the device is unplugged.  But it's not.